# PNG Bit extension

Tags: bitmap, bit-manipulation, png, pixel

I'm writing PNG Decoder and I'm having problems with grayscale images with bit depths < 8.

I am not sure what to do to get full color range.

For example, given that image is using 4 bit depth, and data byte is: `10110010`
I have 2 pixels, `1011` and `0010`. Now, I shift second pixel 4 bits left to occupy high order bits. And here is the problem. Should I duplicate bits so that 2 pixels will be `10111011` and `00100010` or should I just extend last bit so that pixels will be `10111111` and `00100000`. I could not find information about this in PNG spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would this be in the specifications? You are converting your output values, and the specs should not care what you do with your output data. Still, as  Glenn Randers-Pehrson observed, the [official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) contains relevant advice. [Concepts: 4.3.6 Sample depth scaling](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#4Concepts.Scaling) introduces the basics. Recommendations for encoders and decoders are discussed in [12.5 Sample depth scaling](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#12Sample-depth-scaling) for encoders (scaling external data to a supported PNG format), and [13.12 Sample depth rescaling](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#12Sample-depth-scaling) for decoders (scaling a PNG format to a desired output format).

That said, assuming you want a 4 bit value `1111` linearly converted to an 8-bit value of `1111.1111`, then the formula is

```
output = 255 * input / 15
```

Applying the formula to the range 0..15, you get

```
 0: 0000 -> 00000000
 1: 0001 -> 00010001
 2: 0010 -> 00100010
 3: 0011 -> 00110011
 4: 0100 -> 01000100
 5: 0101 -> 01010101
 6: 0110 -> 01100110
 7: 0111 -> 01110111
 8: 1000 -> 10001000
 9: 1001 -> 10011001
10: 1010 -> 10101010
11: 1011 -> 10111011
12: 1100 -> 11001100
13: 1101 -> 11011101
14: 1110 -> 11101110
15: 1111 -> 11111111
```

As you can see, the first four bits are always repeated in the lower bits. That is *exactly* what the formula above does!

```
  255 * input / 15
= input * 255 / 15
= input * 17
= input + input * 16
```

and we end up with

```
output = (input<<4) + input
```

This can be extended to upsample (and downsample) *any* value to another base:

```
newvalue = (oldvalue * max_new) / max_old
```

As `max_new` typically will be odd for bit values, to get proper rounding you can use

```
newvalue = (2 * oldvalue * max_new + max_old) / (2*max_old)
```

Comment: Actually there is advice in the PNG spec (sections entitled "Sample depth scaling" and "Sample depth rescaling") which is equivalent to your answer.

Comment: @Glenn: thanks! I guess this was something I already "knew" and so did not have to see it written out. Running some quick tests, I also found the reported "left bit replication usually gives the same value as linear scaling, and is **never off by more than one**", strangely enough. I can't really put my finger on why that happens...